# Unable to unpack file android-sdk-r22.6.2-windows.zip: error in opening zip file

Tags: android

I want to using the Android studio for develop Android apps. After I installed and run the Android studio this error displayed :
[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: Please check whether you have enough space in drive where you installed your sdk.

Comment: For that, How much space is needed?

Comment: Min 3GB.. and if you are installing whole version like 4 4.1 5 etc then it will take more than 5GB

Comment: I have 6 GB free space. It need?

Comment: Mine one is taking 28 GB so for you space should be more than 15GB

Comment: I delete 30 GB of my files, but this problem not resolved!

Comment: Make sure it is same drive where you installed your sdk?

Comment: Do I have to download This file `android-sdk-r22.6.2-windows.zip`??

Comment: It will be good download and extract SDK first then while installing Android Studio set SDK path there or Download Android Studio with SDK and install it in that directory which have good space.

Comment: `Make sure it is same drive where you installed your sdk?` No These are not same!

Comment: So you have to delete space of your SDK drive(Not android Studio drive) to get it installed.

Comment: I'm familiar in Eclipse-android  Development. Kindly suggest  solution for above error.

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately that is because of sanctions of Google on Iranian users.
In this step Android Studio tries to download android-sdk-r22.6.2-windows.zip but instead of actual file it gets the error page in html format and then try to unzip the html and it leads to generating this error.

Best way is to use a VPN or proxy to change your IP.

We hate you Google.That's All We Know.

Comment: thanks. you're right. just need a VPN. Parchame Iran Balast :-D

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem you could do this instructions step by step:

1. run your antifilter for example psiphone;
2. goto "Default Settings->appearance and settings > System Settings > HTTP Proxy" and set it auto detect proxy settings or [Manual proxy configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQnVU.png) on the "Default Settings->appearance and settings > System Settings > Android SDK" click on [Edit text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB5yo.png);

3.Click on Next

Now your configuration will be done without error.

Answer (score 0):

I had renamed my Android SDK folder due to which this problem occured. As soon as I renamed Android SDK folder back to it's original name, the Android Studio started successfully without showing this error.

This is because Android Studio was not able to find the SDK folder and it was automatically downloading a new SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too, and I live in UAE! So I don't think it's related to Iran.

What I ended up doing was just to close Android studio and re-run the setup  again and everything worked normally.

I hope it helps someone out there.

OS: MAC OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Answer (score 0):

You can simply download the package needed from the Google separately and install it in its default location.

During the setup wizard of Android Studio where it asks for the *SDK package* to be installed just click the button below and chose the destination folder which you've installed the latest SDK package.

After clicking next it will check and say your SDK is up to date and the wizard will complete.

This method works for people who have access issues regarding filtering problems of Google SDK download links during the setup.